# Runscript Error '9' Subscript out of range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I've been trying to wrap my head around using loops and arrays and have put together the below example which takes worksheet names from a table on a worksheet and stores them in array from which another loop runs to add a value in cell A1 in those named spreadsheets based on a value in cell D1 found on the activesheet.

I keep getting a runtime error but I cannot identify what the value the code is looking that keeps tripping up.

The error seems to be located on this line:

Sheets(myArray(x)).Range("A1").Value = EntryValue

Any help on what I've not done correctly is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
Sub WorksheetListLoop()

    Dim myArray() As Variant
    Dim EntryValue As String
    Dim ListRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim x As Long

    'Set the values to go into range
    Set ListRange = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tblArrayList").DataBodyRange

    'Resize array prior to loading data
    ReDim myArray(ListRange.Cells.Count)

    'Loop through each cell in range and store sheetname in array
    For Each cell In ListRange.Cells
        myArray(x) = cell.Value
        x = x + 1
    Next cell

    'Use the value in this cell to put into the sheets in the array
    EntryValue = ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Value

    'Loop through list and add value to cell
    For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        Sheets(myArray(x)).Range("A1").Value = EntryValue
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: This is wrong ActiveSheet("Sheet4") Do you mean Activesheet or Sheet4?

Comment: try to trap your error by putting an on error clause and put a breakpoint in your error clause. with the resume command the cursor will be put back on its original line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is 0 based but you are doing `0 to .Cell.Count` so have an empty position causing the  error. Do to `.Cells.Count -1`

```
ReDim myArray(ListRange.Cells.Count-1)
```

Also, use explicit sheet references not Activesheet and correct the syntax for

```
ActiveSheet("Sheet4")
```

Perhaps,

```
Worksheets("Sheet4")
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say ListRange.Cells.Count is 9. Arrays by default are zero-based, not one-based.

`ReDim myArray(ListRange.Cells.Count)` redims to 0 to 9, a total of 10 array elements.

The following code populates myArray(0) to myArray(8).

```
For Each cell In ListRange.Cells
    myArray(x) = cell.Value
    x = x + 1
Next cell
```

myArray(9) is empty.

This code loops through every element including the one that is empty.

```
For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    Sheets(myArray(x)).Range("A1").Value = EntryValue
Next x
```

On the last iteration when x equals UBound(myArray), you are trying to reference an empty array element.

Easiest solution: put `Option Base 1` at the top of the module sheet with [Option Explicit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyVrl.gif) and move `x = x + 1` above `myArray(x) = cell.Value`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the above. As a newbie to VBA, I appreciate the help very much.